# Is it possible to create a DateTimeZone from an offset?

Tags: php, datetime

The [DateTimeZone](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) constructor only accepts a region name:

```php
new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
```

And not an offset from UTC:

```php
new DateTimeZone('+01:00'); // Unknown or bad timezone (+01:00)
```

However, it is possible to obtain such a DateTimeZone from a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```php
(new DateTime('2012-12-28T00:00:00+01:00'))->getTimezone()->getName(); // +01:00
```

So this is a bit weird. Is there a way to directly obtain a DateTimeZone from an offset?

Comment: That doesn't work. Your links are for `DateTime`, not `DateTimeZone`!

Comment: Reading comprehension fail.  Sorry about that.

Comment: `+01:00` by itself is ambiguous - it could be `Europe/Copenhagen` in winter or `Europe/London` in summer.

Comment: It's not ambiguous, it's a time zone designator as defined by ISO 8601.  Along with a local date-time, it defines a precise instant on the time-line. It's a different concept than a time-zone region, which can refer to one or more offsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to [Rafał's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14068753/759866), the simplest way I've found so far is:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('O', '+01:00')->getTimezone();
```

---

**Edit**

This was a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45528) that has been fixed in PHP 5.5.10. It now works!

Answer (score 2):

Modern answer:

```
new DateTimeZone('+0100');
```

Documentation:

> http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php

Comment: Hence my update: *"This was a bug that has been fixed in PHP 5.5.10. It now works!"*

Answer (score 1):

Check out this function.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php

You'll need to convert hours to seconds and pass them as second parameter.

Sth. like `new DateTimeZone(timezone_name_from_abbr('', 3600, 0))` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that there is any predefined way you wanna go. But if you declare any global function that will return you date and time with the offset added, it might help you.
Example :

```
function getDateTime($format="dd-mm-YY"){

$currDate= date($format);

$currDate=date($format,strtotime("+1 day",$currDate); // or whatever needed instead of +1 day

}
```

Comment: That's not really what I'm trying to achieve!