# Carbon::now() with time-offset result in different behaviors

Tags: laravel-5.1, php-carbon

I'am using `Carbon` for manipulating dates in a laravel project.

```
Carbon::now('+5:30');
```

Above code is working fine in local environment but not in development environment.

This is what i get on `dd(Carbon::now('+5:30'));`

**1 - IN LOCAL ENVIRONMENT** *php version - 5.6.3*

[image]

**2 - IN DEVELOPMENT ENVIRONMENT** *php version - 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14*

[image]

**But** both environment behaves same if i use timezone name instead of time-offset like,

```
 Carbon::now('Asia/Tokyo');
```

Is this something about the *php-version* or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an answer for you after searching for related issues.

It seems that PHP version 5.5.9 had a bug:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14069062/5912664

So you can't use that method with Carbon, but the following should work:

```
Carbon::now()->addHours(5)->addMinutes(30);
```

You can place your servers timezone in there for added accuracy:

```
Carbon::now(date_default_timezone_get())->addHours(5)->addMinutes(30);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change in

```
'timezone' => 'UTC'
```

This time zone must match to your country zone.So replace this UTC with your current zone.

Comment: Correct but what im asking is why its not working in some situations & i need to do as `Carbon::now('+5:30')` because i need to format some times from different countries.

Comment: Changing environment files can have unintended consequences in other places.